# What is the probability that all three tosses result in the same outcome?

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed three times: The probability of zero heads is 1/8 and the probability of zero tails is 1/8.

And my question is: What is the probability that all three tosses result in the same outcome?

So, if P(zero heads)= 1/8 , then that should be the same of p(all tails)?

If so, we could use the Addition Rule which is $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

where A and B are disjoint events, i.e. $A \cap B = \emptyset$, A is the event of tossing all heads and B is the event of tossing all tails.

I'm not sure how to continue after that... would the complement be used?

Comment: If you are confused about this sort of thing, it's not a bad idea to write out all the possibilities.  There are only eight of them and each has probability $\frac 18$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the desired event. Then $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(HHH)+\mathbb{P}(TTT)=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4}.$$