# What is the probability that there is at least one head and at least one tail?

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed three times. The probability of zero heads is 1/8 and the probability of zero tails is 1/8. What is the probability that there is at least one head and at least one tail?

So, if P(zero heads)= 1/8 , then that should be the same of p(all tails)?

We would use the complement rule and Multiplication Rule?

P(at least one head) = 1 - P(no heads) = 1 - 1/8= 7/8
P(at least one tail) = 1 - P(no tails) = 1 - 1/8= 7/8

would I multiply the two values?

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906798/what-is-the-probability-tha-all-three-tosses-result-in-the-same-outcome).  Well, it's the complement of it...in that, either you get the same thing on each toss or you must have at least one $H$ and at least one $T$.  Thus the answers must add to $1$.

Comment: As I suggested on that question, write out all the possibilities.  There are only eight of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of the event *At Least One Heads and one Tails* is *All Heads or All Tails*. Note that *All Heads* and *All Tails* are mutually exclusive (disjoint) events, and so

$$P(\text{All Heads or All Tails}) = P(\text{All Heads}) + P(\text{All Tails})$$

Since you know these probabilities, as demonstrated in your question, you can finish this.

Finally:

$$P(\text{At Least one Heads and At least one Tails}) = 1 - P(\text{All Heads or All Tails})$$

I think lulu's suggestion is a good one too. Besides the fact that it directly answers the question, When writing out all possibilities you get a "feel" for the sample spaces in similar problems.